# How to modify XML and XLSX output from Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've been trying to modify the output (export) of model information from Active Admin for a rails application. I can modify the CSV output using the

```
csv do
  ..
end
```

Is there a method to modify the output of XML or XLXS in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin does not provide tools for customizing xml/json output like it does for csv.

So there are couple options you can do:

- Rewrite [to_xml](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-to_xml) method for you model
- Create .xml.erb template. For example if you have active admin for User, then your template should be in app/views/admin/users/index.xml.erb